# Encountered [E0195] lifetime parameters or bounds on type `Target` do not match the trait declaration when using lazy_static

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

While doing `cargo install 'flutter_rust_bridge_codegen@^2.0.0-dev.0'`, I was hit with the following:

```
error[E0195]: lifetime parameters or bounds on type `Target` do not match the trait declaration
  --> C:\Users\USER\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\console-0.15.7\src\utils.rs:25:1
   |
25 | / lazy_static! {
26 | |     static ref STDOUT_COLORS: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(default_colors_enabled(&Term::stdout()));
27 | |     static ref STDERR_COLORS: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(default_colors_enabled(&Term::stderr()));
28 | | }
   | |_^ lifetimes do not match type in trait
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `__lazy_static_internal` which comes from the expansion of the macro `lazy_static` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

As this wasn't the first machine I installed `flutter_rust_bridge_codegen`, I am pretty sure this is not the problem of the release.

I suspect there is an issue with the cached version of the `lazy_static` crate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug into the cache `%USERPROFILE%\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\lazy_static-1.4.0\src\lib.rs` and found the line that defines `type Target`

The cached version I had was `type Target<'a> = $T;`
I revised it to `type Target = $T;`

Then I rerun `cargo install 'flutter_rust_bridge_codegen@^2.0.0-dev.0'`

Problem **solved**.

Further note:
I had encountered similar problem with my own development and had circumvent using `lazy_static` altogether because I thought my understanding of `lazy_static` usage was wrong.

This time around, I realised the problem didn't just happened to my code.

My "fix" may not be totally correct. But to me, this `<'a>` seem unnecessary and is really painful to handle. Even though imperfect, the fix at least gets me to move on to focus on the things I cared more for.

I cannot find a similar case in SO. So my assumption is this lazy_static issue may be caused by my own ignorance. I am keen to find out what I could have done better.

Comment: Best to avoid `lazy_static` completely in new code. [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.19.0/once_cell/) provides the same functionality without macros, and `std::sync::OnceLock` provides something similar in the standard library (`std::sync::LazyLock` providing the same functionalitiy is still unstable).